# Why is my SQL query leading to a PHP array missing half of the result?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My SQL query is

```
"select stat_name, stat_count 
from directors_stats 
where (id  = 1 or id =2) 
order by id";
```

It returns two rows like `stat1: 123` and `stat2: 456` yet when I execute it in my php script as follows:

```
while($raw = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    print_r($raw);
}
```

The resulting array is

```
[0] => stat2
[stat_name] => stat2
[1] => 456
[stat_count] => 456
```

It looks like mysqli_fetch_array is returnng only the second row, but twice.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array fetches one row from the result.  Read the docs at php.net.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` then you will only get each column ONCE and you may get less confused

Comment: @Devon I figured, but why is it returning it twice?

Comment: It's not, it's putting it in an associative and numerical array like it says in the docs because you didn't specify a type.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns an ASSOC array and a NUMERIC array. Thats wht you are getting confused. That output is from only ONE row.

Comment: So are you SURE that your table has two rows with id's containing 1 AND 2

Comment: What's the line in your code BEFORE the while?